# How to use constant data instead of query field name?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, graphql-codegen, graphql-tag

In my React(Apollo client) App, for creating queries I am using **gql``** tag from **graphql-tag** package, I am wandering if following is somehow possible to achieve:

```
const bookField = 'books'
const GET_BOOKS = gql`
query getBooks {
   ${bookField} {
    id
    title
 }
`
```

So basically to use constant value as a query name?
After this kind of change **graphql-codegen** doesn't generates query and related types,hooks... any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna query field conditionally, the way I see it, is to create different `Fragment`, and based on that, with the hooks auto generated by apollo client and code-gen, you can query different field.

```
// Let's say in this seanario:
const bookField = condition ? 'books' : "otherField"

const GET_BOOKS = gql`
query getBooks {
   ${bookField} {
    id
    title
 }
`

// This should be put in useEffect
// auto gen hooks
const bookField = condition ? useGetBooksQuery() : useGetOtherFieldQuery()
```

Comment: "books" is query name not a field of query, so I just need to extract it in constant, I am not planing to use different name for bookField. BTW thanks for your time.